# Button does not respond on click discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am trying to implement buttons into my discord bot but, the discord bot seems to not respond when the button is clicked. I have done all imports.

```
async def testButton(ctx):
  ticket = await ctx.send(
      "_ _",
      components = [
          Button(label = "Test", style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id="test")
      ]
  )
  interaction = await client.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "test")
  await interaction.send(content='Test')
```

Comment: What library do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line `DiscordComponents(client)` below the declaration of client in the main file. Then this command starts to work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the most common discord library (`discordpy`), you need to add the `client.command()` **decorator** above the function to let `discordpy` know that it is a command:

```py
@client.command()
async def testButton(ctx):
  ticket = await ctx.send(
      "_ _",
      components = [
          Button(label = "Test", style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id="test")
      ]
  )
  interaction = await client.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "test")
  await interaction.send(content='Test')
```

Comment: I have it added

Answer (score 0):

In recent days i faced this error while running discord-components in replit. In olden times it works fines but after some times it is not working properly while in other editor or other projects in replit it works fine.I am not sure how to fix this error but still if you want to send interaction i will suggest you an alternative way that works fine for me. Just replace the last line of the code with embed and use respond for interaction. Like the below code

```py
async def testButton(ctx):
  ticket = await ctx.send(
      "_ _",
      components = [
          Button(label = "Test", style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id="test")
      ]
  )
  interaction = await client.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "test")
  embed=discord.Embed(title="Test")
  await interaction.respond(embed=embed)
```

I hope this works for you